# Concatenate and format text in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to concatenate the `City`, `State` and `Country` columns into something like City, State, Country.

This is my code:

```
Select City + ', ' + State + ', ' + Country as outputText from Places
```

However, because `City` and `State` allow `null` (or empty) value, what happen is, (for example) if the `City` is null/empty, my output will look like `, Iowa, USA`; or say the `State` is empty, then the output will look like `Seattle, , USA`

Is there anyway I can format the output and remove "unnecessary" commas?

Edited: Because of the requirements, I should not use any other mean (such as PL/SQL, Store Procedure) etc., so it has to be plain SQL statement

Comment: What database are you using?  SQL Server, MySQL, etc?

Comment: @GoatCO SQL Server, please read my edit, I should avoid using Stored Procedure

Comment: Select tags for describing your questions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select
  isnull(City, '') +
  case when isnull(City, '') != '' then ', ' else '' end +
  isnull(State, '') + 
  case when isnull(State, '') != '' then ', ' else '' end +
  isnull(Country, '') as outputText 
from 
  Places
```

Comment: Close! There are some syntax and logic error but I have edited your query to fit my requirements.

Comment: If you only have City you will have something like `City, `, so this will not work as described.

Comment: @C.J. lol, well, i'm glad I could get you there.  I was writing that all from memory, so glad you were able to correct any goofs.

Comment: @reece I did not mention in my question very clearly, but Country is `not nullable` and because of that, paqogomez's codes actually work fine.

Comment: You should add `COALESCE` logic (`COALESCE(City,'') != '' THEN ','`).

Comment: @outisnihil, `isnull` is just a limited `coalesce` does the same thing, its just limited to two parameters.

Comment: @paqogomez Thanks, actually I did know that. I'll try to be more clear: if you add either `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` to the condition, you will get a cleaner condition. It would be more clear, for instance, that you need an `AND` and not an `OR`.

Answer (score 1):

Since adding a string with null will result null so if they are null (not empty string) this will give you teh desired result

```
Select isnull(City + ', ','')  + isnull(State + ', ' ,'') + isnull(Country,'') as outputText from Places
```

Comment: It doesn't work if the value is empty instead of null.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [COALESCE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) function.

```
SELECT COALESCE(City + ', ', '') + COALESCE(State + ', ', '')...
```

Answer (score 0):

Not elegant by any means...

- first changes city, state,country to null values if blank
- then interprets that value for null and adds a space before a comma
- then replaces any space comma space  ( , ) with empty set.

Query:

```
SELECT replace(coalesce(Replace(City,'',Null),' ') + ', ' + 
               coalesce(Replace(State,'',Null), ' ' + ', ' + 
               coalesce(replace(Country,''Null),''), ' , ','') as outputText 
FROM Places
```

Assumes no city state or country will contain space comma space.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2012 you can use CONCAT function:

```
select concat(City,', ',State,', ',Country ) as outputText from Places
```